# .Net 4 Task's scheduling clarification?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library, threadpool

From [here](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=J3qPu2gwWtsC&pg=PT119&lpg=PT119&dq=%22The%20.NET%20Framework%20provides%20local%20task%20queues%20for%20each%20worker%22&source=bl&ots=mnKT7KxhrO&sig=lS44hqXS6brmmOpupRV_MV2ZsiU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LHMUUsKJGYbFtAaYm4DgDg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22The%20.NET%20Framework%20provides%20local%20task%20queues%20for%20each%20worker%22&f=false)

> The .NET Framework provides local task queues for each worker thread
>   in the thread pool.Giving different parts of the application their own
>   work queues helps avoid a central bottleneck ( by not accessing the global queue).

[image]

I assume that those queues are for new tasks which comes from the worker thread and not from a regular thread.

**Question :**

But why does the queue (in each worker thread) is running local tasks in a LIFO manner ? where is the fairness ? 
A task which was queued earlier , should run earlier ( FIFO).

What am I missing ?

Comment: The Task class does suffer from having been in the hands of astronaut architects.  Nothing special going on here, the subtasks you add with ContinueWith() run in order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tasks that were just queued are likely to have their working set of memory still in the CPU cache (e.g. Quick Sort recursively enqueueing parts of an array to be sorted). LIFO promotes cache reuse and demotes fairness. But the TPL does not guarantee fairness anyway, and I see few apps which would need that.

Comment: And if you do want fairness, there's [`TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/07/07/9822857.aspx) (which puts the `Task` to the global FIFO queue).

Comment: @svick Are you saying that if I open a sub Task ( from a worker thread) and set `PreferFairness` , it will go to the Global queue ? ( I thought it should go to the local queue)

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yes, that's exactly what that option is for (read the article I linked to).